# Can't install NLTK - UrlLib2 Error

Tags: ubuntu, installation, urllib2, nltk

I already have NLTK installed in one machine (did it one year back). Now I'm trying to install NLTK in a VM I've obtained from the general cluster of my lab. Numpy has been installed. Pip is also there... now I tried to install it using:

```
root@jupiter31:~/FSD# sudo pip install nltk
```

It gives an error saying:-

```
Downloading/unpacking nltk
  Downloading nltk-2.0.4.tar.gz (955kB): 955kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/setup.py) egg_info for package nltk
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.21.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
        to_dir, download_delay)
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
        src = urlopen(url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
        return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
        return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
        raise URLError(err)
    urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.21.tar.gz

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/nltk
```

Not sure how to proceed. I wrote export http proxy command to see if it was a proxy issue. Still giving the same error.

Is it a temporary error from server side or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same error when trying to install nltk, except that instead of `Connection refused` I get the error `<urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>`.

Have you tried using the following syntax?

```
sudo pip install --proxy="myproxy:port" nltk
```